# flat tyre even after replacing the tube?

Tags: maintenance, tire, innertube, puncture

So I bought a used Specialized Sirrus 2011 model as my first bike (so I'm new here) recently and I love riding it, light weight, smooth handling and comfy to ride. Rear wheel was flat when I bought it so guy gave me some money to replace the tube.

I took the bike home and removed the tyre (tyre size is 700*28cc), took out the tube and I could see a puncture on the tube when I inflate it. Was quite happy as I found the reason for the flat tyre. I replaced the tube ride for about 30 mins and put it back in the garage. But on the very next day, the tyre was flat again.

I took the tube out, inflated it but couldn't find a puncture. So I left the inflated tube for few hours and could see that it's deflated a bit. I checked the rim to see if there are any spokes sticking out and no, seems it's all good. Couldn't find anything on the tyre as well.

So anyway, I inflated even more, hoping to find the puncture in the tube. I was squeezing the tube and it got BLASTED!

Now I'm wondering what to do? Should I try with another tube? Also the given that the rear tyre is quite worn out and could see wear marks (rubber on the top center has brown color here and there), and has fibres coming out from sidewalls.

If I put a new tyre and a tube, this should solve my issue right? As there are no visible spoke problem with the rim. This's driven me really impatient, what should I do?

Comment: Hello and wlcome to bicycles. Please use the search function before asking a question that seems really obvious. Are you sure this [isn't a duplicate](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=fix+flat)? [Of this](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/fixing-a-flat-how-to-find-the-piercing-object) or [this](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-i-fix-a-puncture) or [perhaps this](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34833/unpatchable-hole-on-rim-side/34843#34843) etc...

Comment: yes I have gone through some of them. My concerns are: As I have wasted a new tube and can't find anything with the rim or the tyre and also given my tyre is not in a good condition, is it a wise choice to try putting a new tube without replacing the tyre?

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34211/i-cannot-go-30-miles-without-a-flat-i-cant-figure-out-what-the-problem-is/34245#34245  (short answer:  Look at the rim tape / spoke drilled thru holes)

Comment: I've tagged this question "puncture" for you. It might be helpful for you to search for other questions with this tag. (You can do this by typing *[puncture]* in the search box.)

Comment: "Was quite happy as I found the reason for the flat tyre."  You didn't find the reason.   You found the hole in the tube that is a symptom of the reason.  When you remove a flat tube, keep the orientation of the tube the same as the wheel.  When you find the hole in the tube, you know what area of the wheel (or tire) you need to check.  If you didn't find out what made the hole and fix it, you haven't fixed the flat.

Comment: " you know what area of the wheel (or tire) you need to check." - yes I did that. the puncture was on the rim side. I then inspected the rimtape but couldn't see any damages and feels nothing when running your finger along..?

Answer (score 1):

Start by replacing your tyre.  If you can see any part of the fibres at all, then it is long overdue replacing!  Buy a new tube too.

Then, inspect the rim and rimtape, if anything looks like it may chafe or cause an issue, then repair / replace it.

Tubes go flat if left for a long time in any case. If you buy a decent tube, they will keep their pressure for longer. I only buy Schwalbes for my roadie and easily pay more than $10 a tube, but I ride competitively, and I know that they will keep their pressure for at least a month before needing topping up.

Comment: "inspect the rim and rimtape" - isn't it just the rim tape? if the rim tape is undamaged/no holes, puncture can't be due to the rim right?

Comment: @KillBill It'll depend on how your rim is taped. If it is taped only around the bottom of the groove over the top of the spokes, then you may want to check the sides too.